# How to parse an object obtained through a Axios GET request Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm retrieving a json object through the axios get request and I'. attempting to retrieve the name attribute for every object in the results array. when I'm console logging it, it gives me an undefined error? But if i console log data.results, I see the full list of objects?

Api used - https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character

```
module.exports = (app) => {
 app.get("/api/users/london", async (req, res) => {
  axios
   .get("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
   .then(({ data }) =>
     console.log(
       data.array.forEach((element) => {
         element.name;
       })
     )
    )
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
   });
 });
};


TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at /Users/user/workspace/morty- demo/routes/userRoutes.js:20:22
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory: `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` means that somewhere, you're trying to execute `forEach` on `undefined`. The only place where you're doing that is on `data.array`. Conclusion: `data` does not have an `array` property. And if we look at the data returned by the API, indeed, it does not. It has a `results` property, though -> `data.results.forEach()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `data.array` which doesn't seem to be a property of the data object returned. You want to call `.forEach` on the array itself, `data.results`.

This modified code should work, though it might need some tweaks.

```
app.get("/api/users/london", async (req, res) => {
  axios
   .get("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
   .then(({ data }) =>
     data.results.forEach((element) => {
       console.log(element.name);
     })
    )
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
   });
 });
```

Comment: such a minor error. I didnt see the "array". Thank you @brent

Comment: there's still a bug to be fixed. console.log should be inside forEach or else its useless. or use map instead of forEach

Answer (score 1):

Use map to query each name property

```js
     console.log(
       data.array.map((element) => {
         return element.name;
       })
     )
```